Parsing a large Json array in Haskell and strictly converting its elements
I have a json file containing (among other things) a large nested array of multiprecision floating point numbers. Each floating point number is a quoted string of digits, e.g. "3.14159265358979323846264338". I would like to parse the file and, as each element is read, immediately convert it to a numerical datatype (specifically a multiprecision float from this mpfr library). The reason is that multiprecision floats take up much less memory than the corresponding string of digits. I am willing to store a large array of floats in memory, but I do not want to store all the text from the file in memory.
I am aware of json streaming libraries like json-stream. However, I do not know how to force the conversion of underlying ByteStrings to floats during the parsing process. Naively it seems like I will just build up an array of thunks with ByteStrings inside until the file is fully parsed, and then afterwards when the final value is forced, those thunks will be converted to floats and the ByteStrings will be gc'd. How can I avoid this?

The "obvious" approach is a strict data structure like Data.StrictVector or an array. Have you considered and rejected this?

Can you explain a bit more how this would work?

Suppose, for a moment, that you're willing to store these as Doubles.
You can use json-stream to parse directly into a Vector. If your JSON file just had plain numbers instead of quoted strings, it would be as simple as:
main1 :: IO ()
main1 = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_noquotes.json"
    let nums = parseLazyByteString (arrayOf real) f :: [Double]
        !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

Since you've got quotation marks, you need a slightly more complicated parser. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but the following works:
main2 :: IO ()
main2 = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str) 
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f]
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

In any event, run on a 10 million element array of copies of your pi (10 million copies of "3.14159265358979323846264338", for a total 300M file size) this version runs relatively quickly and reaches an enormous maximum residency of 1G, but that's -- of course -- because it's generating a vector of thunks for parsing. Storing the thunks themselves plus all the byte strings from the 300M file with their overhead easily gets us to 1G.
However, it's easy enough to force these parsing thunks.  Just write:
main3 :: IO ()
main3 = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ num
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f
               , let !num = read (T.unpack str) ] -- force the thunks
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

This takes significantly longer to run, but the maximum residency is reduced to 200M.  That may still seem pretty big, but a boxed vector of 10 million Doubles needs 2 words per Double, for the D# constructor and the underlying Double# value itself.  That's 16 bytes per element, so 160M for our example.
You can do better by using an unboxed vector, which drops all the unnecessary D# constructors:
let !dat = VU.fromList nums  -- VU = Data.Vector.Unboxed

In this case, you don't have to force the thunks because they will be forced as part of creating the unboxed vector.
This runs in 130M maximum residency, of which about 80M is used for storing the vector.
Note that using a Storable vector (i.e., VS.fromList from Data.Vector.Storable`) is slower, but has equivalent space usage.  And, again the thunks don't need to be forced, as it will happen automatically in the process of creating the storable vector.
So, what about Rounded from the package you mention?
Well, it maybe isn't a great choice if efficient space usage is a consideration.  Internally, it's a data type with four fields (a precision, a sign, an exponent, and a byte array), so unboxed it's five words (constructor plus four fields) plus a byte array (header, a word for the size, and a payload).  So for a Rounded TowardZero 128, we're probably talking about 56 bytes of overhead plus a 16-byte payload, so 72 bytes?  Sure enough, if we build a vector of Roundeds without forcing it:
main5 :: IO ()
main5 = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str)
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f]
               :: [Rounded TowardZero 128]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

it completes quickly and needs about a gigabyte to store parsing thunks, but if we force the parsing thunks:
main6 :: IO ()
main6 = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ num
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f
               , let !num = read (T.unpack str) ] -- force the thunks
               :: [Rounded TowardZero 128]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

it takes a lot longer to run and reaches a max residency of 740M.  That's a "savings" over the thunks, but it's not a very big difference (and, in fact, it would perform worse for numbers like "42.1" (four bytes, in string form).
Also, since there are no Unboxed or Storable instances for Rounded, we have no options for improving the efficiency of this representation.
Here are my various test cases:
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main (main) where

import Data.List
import Data.Scientific
import Numeric.Rounded
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.JsonStream.Parser
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS

writeExamples :: IO ()
writeExamples = do
  let count = 1000000  -- only a million, for quick testing
  writeFile "/tmp/array_noquotes.json" $ "[" <> intercalate "," (replicate count "3.14159265358979323846264338") <> "]"
  writeFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json" $ "[" <> intercalate "," (replicate count "\"3.14159265358979323846264338\"") <> "]"

-- parse the no quote version, leaving thunks in place
main_noquotes :: IO ()
main_noquotes = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_noquotes.json"
    let nums = parseLazyByteString (arrayOf real) f :: [Double]
        !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse the quote version, leaving thunks in place
main_quotes :: IO ()
main_quotes = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str)
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f]
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse the quote version, forcing the vector element thunks
mainV_forced :: IO ()
mainV_forced = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ num
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f
               , let !num = read (T.unpack str) ] -- force the thunks
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse the quote version into an unboxed vector
-- (elements are implicitly forced)
mainVU :: IO ()
mainVU = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str)
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f]
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = VU.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse the quote version into a storable vector
-- (elements are implicitly forced)
mainVS :: IO ()
mainVS = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str)
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f ]
               :: [Double]
    let !dat = VS.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse to Rounded, leave as thunks
mainRounded_thunks :: IO ()
mainRounded_thunks = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ read (T.unpack str)
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f]
               :: [Rounded TowardZero 128]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse to Rounded, forcing the element thunks
mainRounded_forced :: IO ()
mainRounded_forced = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ num
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f
               , let !num = read (T.unpack str) ] -- force the thunks
               :: [Rounded TowardZero 128]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

-- parse to Scientific, forcing the element thunks
mainScientific :: IO ()
mainScientific = do
    f <- BL.readFile "/tmp/array_quotes.json"
    let nums = [ num
               | str <- parseLazyByteString (arrayOf string) f
               , let !num = read (T.unpack str) ] -- force the thunks
               :: [Scientific]
    let !dat = V.fromList nums
    pure ()

main :: IO ()
main = mainRounded_forced


Thanks so much -- this helps a lot! There are some complicating circumstances that I'm not sure how to deal with. Firstly, Rounded isn't optional for me because the floats are actually about 1024 binary digits. Secondly, I actually have a 7-fold nested array of floats [[[[[[[Rounded TowardZero 1024]]]]]]] I am not sure how to deal with such a thing with json-stream. Thirdly, the nested array is inside another json object. Finally, should I be using lazy IO? I thought it wasn't considered a good idea.

Is this a ragged array, or are all dimensions fixed?

It’s a ragged array.

Just some notes to elaborate on the answer above:

conduits, streaming etc. are so much better than lazy IO, but that depends on your situation, size of the files etc.
If I understand correctly, you need to convert a JS string to some mpfr type; so just use the fmap on the parser itself. Given that Haskell is lazy, it's not quite obvious in which stage the conversion occurs, but at least it is much cleaner

parseLazyByteString (arrayOf (stringToMpftNum <$> string)) f

